# Multiplying entire columns of dataframe by a value in R

Tags: r

I am trying to multiply two columns in my dataframe by a value. I tried creating a dataframe out of the value. It looks something like this:

```
df1<-data.frame(F1=d$X2012,F2=d$Sample...Size)
```

`df1`

`C<-data.frame(C=c(0.9174311926605,0.9174311926605,0.9174311926605,0.9174311926605)) C df1 * C$c`
df1 * C$c

F1      F2
137.1   109
36.55   109
0.75    109
7.6     109

C

0.9174312
0.9174312
0.9174312
0.9174312

But I keep getting this error

Error in FUN(left, right) : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Any solutions to work my way around this?

Answer (score 2):

We can use

```
 df[1:2] <- df[1:2] * value
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
df <-
  data.frame(
    x1 = round(runif(100, min = 100, max=170)),
    x2 = sample(1:10, 100, replace = T),
    x3 = round(runif(100), 2)
  )
```

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- df %>% 
  mutate(across(x2:x3, ~. * x1))
```